# Dealers in OTCs (over-the-counter)

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

"However dealers (of the OTCs) resist the participation of non-dealers and accuse non-dealers of taking liquidity without exposing themselves to the risks of providing liquidity." The above is the complaint from dealers in OTCs to the movement of non-dealers into the OTCs, therefore making OTCs similar to an Exchange.

Can someone please explain WHY "participation of non-dealers takes liquidity without getting exposed to the risks of providing liquidity."

Thanks!!

Quote from: https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/basics/markets.htm